# Filtering an array: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')

Tags: reactjs, redux, filter, slice, lowercase

Trying to set up a filter/search function in a slice, but keep getting this error. I've checked documentation, tutorials, everything I can possibly think of, and still keep getting the same result.

Here is my code, attached screenshot for good measure, as well:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    filteredEntries: []
}

const filterSlice = createSlice ({
    name: "filter",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        FILTER_ENTRIES(state, action) {
            const {entries, search} = action.payload
            const tempEntries = entries.filter((entry) => 
                entry.title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) || entry.author.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
            )
            state.filteredEntries = tempEntries
        }
    }
})

export const {FILTER_ENTRIES} = filterSlice.actions

export const selectFiltered = (state) => state.filter.filteredEntries;

export default filterSlice.reducer
```

[image]

Have tried passing parameters into the array, using different variables instead of "entry/entries," using entry?.title.toLowerCase()

Comment: how did you call the `FILTER_ENTRIES` in the component

Comment: useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(FILTER_ENTRIES({ entries, search }))
    }, [entries, search, dispatch])

Comment: What is the inital state for `entries` and `search` ?